# Loading raw files into SQL Server database using python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

My below code uses `pandas` library and it populates `mydataframe` and then stores an Excel file locally on my machine.

```
pandas.DataFrame(mydataframe, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).to_excel("C:/Desktop/Output.xlsx")
```

Later, I import the created file `Output.xlsx` and store it into my SQL Server database in `varbinary` format using SQL Server Bulk Insert like below:

```
Query = '''
        DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);
        SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '%s', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Doc;
        INSERT INTO[TEST].[dbo].[Files]([file],[file_name])
        select @Document, ?                 
        '''%Excelfilepath
values = (file_name)
connsql = self.sql_connection()
connsql.cursor().execute(Query, values)
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

Is there a way using pandas or other python library where I can create file on the fly and store into SQL Server database without creating file locally and then importing it into the database?